# how project onto itself works?(snap)

Tags: snapping

I cant think of projections that how it works own my own I don't know why projection needed in snapping I want to know how projection works in snapping.

Answer (score 1):

When *Project onto Self* is disabled, you can only snap to geometry of other objects.
It's useful when you go to *Edit mode* with multiple objects at once.

<sup>Notice I can only snap to the other object's vertices unless I enable *Project onto Self*.</sup>
[image]

Answer (score 1):

...Why 'Projection'? Because sometimes that's what it is.. (actually, internally, it *always* is). Here, the move is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> constrained to XY, so the snap is in X and Y only, projected down Z.

[image]